# Sending push to Android using SNS

Tags: android, .net, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

I'm really puzzled about to get the whole chain of sending a push from my .NET backend to my android app using Amazon SNS.

I'm using [JustSaying](https://github.com/justeat/JustSaying) on my backend to send my messages to SNS which is working when I tested it with a email subscriper. This is the code I'm using to send the push:

```
var publisher = CreateMeABus.InRegion(RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1.SystemName)
                .WithSnsMessagePublisher<Push>();


publisher.Publish(new Push("Hello"));
```

And push class looks like this:

```
public class Push : Message
    {

        public Push(string body)
        {
            Body = body;
        }

        public string Body { get; set; }

    }
```

Now my problem is, how to I send this push to my specific device?

I created an app on https://developers.google.com for google cloud messaging and have a applicationkey and senderid.

I also set up an API project/app on http://console.developers.google.com and enabled the API for cloud messaging.

In AWS SNS console I also created an application and supplied the above mentioned applikationkey which generated a ARN for the Google Android Platform.

In my android app I'm running this code:

```
try{

GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
     String regId = gcm.register("my-sender-id ");

} catch(IOException e){

}
```

I'm fumbling in the dark here and can't find any good turtorial on how to set this up. AWS documentation seems to cover only small parts and seems to be outdated.

Any help on pointing me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the developer guide of SNS http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-gcm.html. In short:

- Get GCM device token (or regId) as in your code
- Register your device to SNS by calling CreatePlatformEndpointRequest with your device token. You will get a platform endpoint ARN which is the identifier of this device in SNS.
- Send notification to the device. Use Publish to publish notification to the platform endpoint ARN

Alternatively, you can subscribe your device to a particular SNS topic. Then you will be able to publish a notification to the topic, and SNS will broadcast it to all subscribers.

Comment: Thanks! It took some trial and error to get it to work. Your answer is correct but I also documented the details in the steps here: http://www.appdelight.se/blog/2015/8/17/sending-push-notifications-from-aspnet-to-android-using-amazon-sns

Comment: @RikardAskelöf:   Hi, that link is not working now. Can you please describe the steps here. Actually when I pass PlatformEndpointARN (instead of TopicARN) to publish() method, it throws exception: InvalidParameter:Topic Name.  I have PlatformEndpointARN only and want to send push notification directly to that device's platformEndpointARN.

Comment: Sorry, I took down the site but you can find the blog post here if it's to any help https://web.archive.org/web/20190109094712/http://www.appdelight.se/blog/